# Django 2.2: regex url match

Tags: python, django, middleware

i need to create a list of urls that one of my middlewares should ignore.

i need to ignore `/admin/` and any url that comes after it.

how can i proceed ?

Comment: Could you please show your URL patterns ?

Comment: You'll need to show some of the code from the middleware.

Comment: Why do you iclude `admin` then? Just remove it from the `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, by "any URL that comes after it", you mean URLs like "/admin/my_app/my_model/...", then you can just use `.startswith()`:

```
if not request.path.startswith('/admin/'):
    # do things
```

If, instead, you want to ignore URLs that are listed after `/admin/` in your `urls.py`, you could iterate over the `url_patterns` of the default resolver and stop if you hit `/admin/` before any other pattern matches.
Note that just because that seems to be possible doesn't mean that it is a good idea ;)

Here is some code that *might* work, but it will most likely not cover any edgecases:

```
from django.urls.exceptions import Resolver404
from django.urls.resolvers import get_resolver

def pattern_after_admin(request):
    """
    Returns True if the request URL matches a pattern listed
    after the `/admin/` pattern or no pattern at all.
    """
    resolver = get_resolver()
    after_admin = False
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
        try:
            pattern.resolve(request.path)
        except Resolver404:
            try:
                pattern.resolve('/admin/')
            except Resolver404:
                pass
            else:
                after_admin = True
                break
        else:
            break
    return after_admin
```

Comment: well my issue was, i had to create an array of regex url that the middleware has to match on , the solution was pretty easy i was just looking too hard into it ... but your solution might help someone down the road, i'll accept it.